# resize panel width according to form maximizing in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a windows application in `C#`.

In that, there is a `panel` and there is a `line shape` in the just right to the `panel`.

The Form State is `maximized` only. So here when it runs, the `panel` width is not extending till near the `line shape`.

So I need to extend the panel width when the form in the maximized state.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WinForms tag is missing here I guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) property of the panel during Design time. 
You can find it in PropertyGrid of panel control.

Comment: I added it. But I need to extend the panel width just before line shape, like when the form is in minimized state.

Comment: So you use Anchor property and the control remains non resized ?

Comment: I added the anchor property, that time, it is extending after the line shape. So I removed the right anchor, but now the width of panel remains unchanged.

Comment: @ullas: do you in design window set panel with desired size already (even if design time window in not full screen)?

Comment: In minimized state, its showing perfectly sir. In maximized state the width remains the same.